# How to downcast a shared_ptr in the case of virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, downcast, virtual-inheritance

Suppose I have a class `C`, inheriting from `B`, itself virtually inheriting from `A`:

```
class A {};
class B : virtual public A {};
class C : public B {};
```

Now suppose I have a `std::shared_ptr<A>` managing an object which I know for sure is of some class inheriting `B` (e.g., of class `C`), and I even happen to have it available as a raw `B` pointer, in a way equivalent to the minimal example below:

```
B * pb = new C;
std::shared_ptr<A> spa(pb);
```

Now **I want to downcast the `std::shared_ptr<A>` to a `std::shared_ptr<B>`**. I can't use `static_pointer_cast` because the inheritance is virtual. I could use `dynamic_pointer_cast` but it seems an overkill given that I already have the object available as a raw `B` pointer.

Is the following code the appropriate way to achieve my goal?

```
std::shared_ptr<B> spb(spa, pb);
```

It seems that yes, but I'd like some confirmation from someone who knows better (I never had to use the aliasing constructor before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the following code the appropriate way to achieve my goal?

Yes. In both cases (your alternative and `dynamic_pointer_cast`), you get a `shared_ptr` who's `operator->` will return a reference to a `B`. And in both cases, it is the object `A` which will have `delete` called upon it when all references are destroyed. In all ways they will behave the same.

Which also means that if you *don't* define a `virtual` destructor in `A`, then in both cases, your code will break upon the deletion of `A`.

That being said, there's nothing "overkill" about using a `dynamic_pointer_cast` in this circumstance.

Comment: Thx! Yes, `A` does have a virtual destructor (like all classes in this inheritance hierarchy). By "overkill", I meant that the overhead of using RTTI seems superfluous in this scenario where I don't need it.